# Generate variable names in loop with name convention changing

Tags: python, string, list, loops, ascii

I am trying to generate a large list of variables, but some of the variables may have subparts to them. The code below is where I am currently at.

```
import string

Num_Phases = 4          # Number of Phases
Subphases = [2, 3]      # Which Phases have Subphases
Num_Subphases = [2, 2]  # How Many Phases the respective Subphase have

Phases = []
for i in range(1, Num_Phases + 1):
    if i < 10:
        # Start with regular name Convention
        PhaseName = "Phase-0%s" %i
        # Check to see if phase has subphase
        for n in range(1, len(Num_Subphases) + 1): 
            if Subphases[n - 1] == i:
                # If there is a Subphase, Check how many Subphases
                for m in range(1, Num_Subphases[n - 1] + 1):
                    # for each subphase define a phase name
                    PhaseName = ("Phase-0%s" %i) + ('').join(string.ascii_lowercase[m-1])
                # Combine Phases into list
                Phases.append(PhaseName)            
        Phases.append(PhaseName)
```

I am currently getting a result of:

```
['Phase-01', 'Phase-02b', 'Phase-02b', 'Phase-03b', 'Phase-03b', 'Phase-04']
```

But I am wanting it to be:

```
['Phase-01', 'Phase-02a', 'Phase-02b', 'Phase-03a', 'Phase-03b', 'Phase-04']
```

This is going to be for a very large data set, but am using this as an example.

Comment: Those are strings in a list, what does this have to do with variable names?

Comment: I need them in list format for another part of my code.

Comment: Why use `range(1, len(Num_Subphases) + 1)` instead of `range(0, len(Num_Subphases))`? Then you won't have to keep writing `n-1`.

Comment: I have no reasoning, I just didn't think to do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m will always be set to the max value of the range when you added it to the list phases. You are overwriting PhaseName before you added it to the Phases list. You could move the appending inside the m loop, checking for duplicates to avoid adding them.

```
for m in range(1, Num_Subphases[n - 1] + 1):
            # for each subphase define a phase name
            PhaseName = ("Phase-0%s" %i) + ('').join(string.ascii_lowercase[m-1])
            # Combine Phases into list
            if PhaseName not in Phases:
               Phases.append(PhaseName)
```

Comment: When I added that to the code, it ended up giving me:  
 
`['Phase-01', 'Phase-02a', 'Phase-02b','Phase-02b', 'Phase-03a',
 'Phase-03b', 'Phase-03b', 'Phase-04']`

Comment: The last ones are being added twice because of the second append PhaseName after the loop. If you add the `If PhaseName not in Phases:` before the second time you do `Phases.append(PhaseName)` it should solve this issue.

Comment: That was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible apporach without using too many nested fors is to build an array that indicates the number of subphases of each phase, then you can use a doble for in a list comprehesion to build the final result

```
phases_arr = [1 for i in range(Num_Phases)]
for isub, numsub in zip(Subphases, Num_Subphases):
    phases_arr[isub-1] = numsub + 1

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

phases = ["Phase-%02d%s" % (i+1, alphabet[k-1] if k > 0 else "") for i in range(len(phases)) for k in range(phases[i])]
```